# Чтобы пропс изменяемый в род. компоненте изменялся и в дочерней компоненте Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, nuxt.js

Есть переменная которая изменяется в родительской компоненте, я передаю эту переменную в дочернюю компоненту и нужно сделать так чтобы эта переменная при изменении в род. компоненте сразу же менялась и в дочернем:

```
<template>
  <div>
      <AboutSection
        :changeInfo="changeInfo" // Передаю пропс
      />
      <IFbutton white :click="() => changeInfo = !changeInfo"> // Изменяю переменную
          Back
      </IFbutton>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import AboutSection from "@/components/sections/about-section";
import IFbutton from "@/components/buttons/if-button";

export default {
  components: {
    IFbutton,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      changeInfo: false,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Проблема в том что когда я отслеживаю переменную в род. компоненте то все изменяется, но когда смотрю на нее через дочернюю, то она всегда false

```
<template>
    <section class="about-section">
        <b-row>
            <b-col offset="3" cols="4">
                <div class="about-section__description">
                    <p v-if="!changeInfo" class="body-3 about-section__description__text">
                        Test
                    </p>
                </div>
            </b-col>
        </b-row>
    </section>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    props: {
        changeInfo: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: false,
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: в дочернем компоненте используйте watch или computed

Comment: Вы не обьявили компоненту "AboutSection"

Answer (score 0):

```
<IFbutton white :click="() => changeInfo = !changeInfo"> // Изменяю переменную
```

В приведённом фрагменте вы не обрабатываете событие, а передаёте в качестве пропса с именем `click` для компонента `IFbutton` функцию.

Вам необходимо указать `@click` (либо использовать директиву `v-on:`, если кодстайл на вашем проекте это подразумевает), но, т. к. обработчик вешается на компонент, то необходимо добавить `.native` ([больше про `.native`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components))